# Using Less mixin variable as a property value

Tags: css, less

I'm looking to supply a property name through a Less Mixin.
I'm some what new to preprocessors and have been jumping
between Less and Sass on various projects. What I'm trying
to do is something like this:

```
  .prefix-prop(@prop; @value) {
    -moz-@{prop}: @value;
    -ms-@{prop}: @value;
    -webkit-@{prop}: @value;
    @{prop}: @value;
  }
```

I see collections of mixins that will have a mixin for
every css property. Why have that if you can just use
one function for all of that? That leads me to believe
that this cannot be done. Though I cannot seem to find
a definitive answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's worth noting that blindly adding prefixes to every single property that may need prefixes is a good way to add unnecessary bloat.  Note that the Compass library for Sass only adds prefixes as necessary for the property in question.

Comment: Agreed, I'm just using that as an example. I've heard very good things  compass but haven't used it. I've also used prefixr sublime text package which does a similar thing in terms of prefixing properties. I may just rely on that until less implements the update. Good call on pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature **is** being added (according to the LESS devs), but still hasn't shipped. I'd recommend following the commits on GitHub.

Interesting reading in this issue > https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/36